# cannot write to certain directory using CentOS distro

Tags: php, centos, mkdir

I have a script that will generate an image then upload it in a certain directory. The script works fine, however uploading it in the CentOS server, it won't work anymore. By debugging, I have found out that this is a permission denied issue. I am forced to `chmod -R 777 certain_directory` to make it work.

I am not convince with this, I can't set the directory ownership to `www-data` I'm used to when I am using Debian. Any workaround for this?

Comment: check what user apache is running as in centos. could be `apache` or `httpd` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# egrep ^User /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
User apache
```

So just chown the files to apache...